# Where in the constellation Camelopardalis is Gliese 445?

Tags: voyager, stars

Gliese 445 (Gl 445 or AC +79 3888) is an M-type main sequence star in the northern part of the constellation Camelopardalis. In about 38,000 years Voyager 1 will make its closest approach to it.
Roughly, where on this map is Gliese 445 located?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliese_445) it is located here:

[image: Gliese 445 wikipedia]

> Right Ascension: 11h 47m 41.3885s
>
> Declination: +78° 41' 28.179"

Which on your star chart is about here:

[image: modified star chart]

Comment: Great thanks. Other sources place the star in the Ursa Minor constellation which makes sense as it is half way between both.

Comment: Astronomical gerrymandering by the Camel, I see.

Comment: @StarfishPrime *Giraffa camelopardalis* is the Giraffe (literally camel with leopard spots), still it's a nice geogiraffical explanation for the shape!

Comment: @bob1 that'll teach me not to double check meanings before commenting.